# Why does read_csv2 read a data that should be a number or a character?

Tags: r, dataframe, csv

With the following code I would like to import a thousand (small) csv files:

```
library(readr)

ldf <- list() # creates a list
listcsv <- dir(pattern = "*.csv") # creates the list of all the csv files in the directory
for (k in 1:length(listcsv)){
  ldf[[k]] <- read_csv2(listcsv[k])
  ldf[[k]] <- as.data.frame(ldf[[k]])
}
```

The operations seem to have been successful because the files have all been loaded into the list `ldf`. Anyway, some of them seem to show an issue. The first two columns of these thousand files should be `chr` but just very few of them have the second column of POSIXct format. I don't know why. The values in this column are:

```
0840-07-11
0840-07-11
0840-07-11
0840-07-11
0840-07-11
0840-07-11
0840-07-11
0840-07-11
```

whereas instead they should be:

```
08400711
08400711
08400711
08400711
08400711
08400711
08400711
08400711
```

Comment: You can specify `col_types` to read as a specific type ie. `col_types = "c"` if all columns are character or as a list i.e. `col_types = list(col_character(), col_character(), ...)`

Comment: @akrun, thank you but `read_csv2(listcsv[k],col_types = "c")` doesn't seem to work. If I use  `str` I still see the POSIXct format

Comment: how many columns are there in each of the list

Comment: Can you try the solution posted and see if that helps?  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, the `col_types` specified as "c" will convert only the first column to `character`.  If we need to force all columns to `character`, specify the `.default` (in case we don't know the number of columns before) or replicate `"c"` as `"ccc"` (equal to number of columns)

```
library(readr)
df1 <- read_csv(readr_example("mtcars.csv"), col_types = cols(.default = "c"))
> str(df1)
spec_tbl_df [32 × 11] (S3: spec_tbl_df/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ mpg : chr [1:32] "21" "21" "22.8" "21.4" ...
 $ cyl : chr [1:32] "6" "6" "4" "6" ...
 $ disp: chr [1:32] "160" "160" "108" "258" ...
 $ hp  : chr [1:32] "110" "110" "93" "110" ...
 $ drat: chr [1:32] "3.9" "3.9" "3.85" "3.08" ...
 $ wt  : chr [1:32] "2.62" "2.875" "2.32" "3.215" ...
 $ qsec: chr [1:32] "16.46" "17.02" "18.61" "19.44" ...
 $ vs  : chr [1:32] "0" "0" "1" "1" ...
 $ am  : chr [1:32] "1" "1" "1" "0" ...
 $ gear: chr [1:32] "4" "4" "4" "3" ...
 $ carb: chr [1:32] "4" "4" "1" "1" ...
```